# Two questions concerning series involving the Möbius function and trigonometric functions

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analytic-number-theory, supremum-and-infimum, mobius-function

Let for integers $n\geq 1$ the Möbius function denoted as $\mu(n)$. See the definition of this arithmetic function from this [MathWorld's article.](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MoebiusFunction.html)

I wodered two questions about series involving the Möbius function.

> **Question.**
>
> A) Can you find real numbers $0<\alpha<\beta<1$ satisfing $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\mu(n)}{n^3}\sin (n\pi \alpha)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\mu(n)}{n^3}\sin (n\pi \beta)=0\,?\tag{1}$$
>   At least, can we justify that these numbers $\alpha$ and $\beta$ do exist?
>
> B) Can you provide me hints to get an approximation of $$\sup \left\{  \left| \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\mu(n)}{n}\sin(n\pi x) \right|:x\in(0,1)  \right\}\,?\tag{2} $$
>   **Thanks you in advance.**

Comment: For arbitrary $(q,s)\in \mathbb{Q}\times \mathbb{C}$ any sum of the form $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\mu(n)}{n^{{\large s}}}\text{sin}(n\pi q)$ can (provided it converges) be evaluated in terms of a linear combination of Dirichlet $L$ functions. Also clearly for any $x\in \mathbb{R}$ we can find a sequence of rational numbers $(q_1,q_2,q_3,\cdots)$ such that $\lim_{k\to\infty}q_k=x$ so you could express your sum as a weird limit of sums of $L$ functions. However the the linear combinations will depend on each rational number $q_k$ in the sequence so this might not really be useful either...

Comment: Many thanks @Ethan you've great knowledges in analytic number theory.

Comment: Haha I'm flattered @user243301, but relative to a vast number of users on this site I'd say my knowledge is rather dismissal. The fact I'm unsure of you're problem, shouldn't really in any way reflect the degree to which it can be simplified/solved etc. those were just my 2 cents so to speak upon looking at it.